# How to filter result based on column values

Tags: mysql

I have this result set in my query.

```
+-------------+-------------+-----------+----------+------------------+---------------+----------------+
| Branch Name |  Client ID  |   Name    |  Loans   | Savings Deposits | Time Deposits | Share Capital  |
+-------------+-------------+-----------+----------+------------------+---------------+----------------+
| Main Office | 01-029203-1 | Doe, John |     0.00 |             0.00 |          0.00 |           0.00 |
| Main Office | 01-012314-1 | Doe, John | 51200.75 |            61.26 |      15000.00 |           0.00 |
| Main Office | 01-929828-3 | Doe, Jane |  3000.00 |             0.00 |       8000.00 |           0.00 |
| Main Office | 01-992830-4 | Doe, Jane |  5240.44 |            46.00 |       2000.00 |           0.00 |
+-------------+-------------+-----------+----------+------------------+---------------+----------------+
```

I want to filter out that if one of the Client IDs of a certain Client Name (Example: Doe, John with Client ID of 01-029203-1) have 0 balance on all 4 accounts (Loans, Savings Deposits, Time Deposit and Share Capital), all instances of that client will not be included.

just like this:

```
+-------------+-------------+-----------+----------+------------------+---------------+----------------+
| Branch Name |  Client ID  |   Name    |  Loans   | Savings Deposits | Time Deposits | Share Capital  |
+-------------+-------------+-----------+----------+------------------+---------------+----------------+
| Main Office | 01-929828-3 | Doe, Jane |  3000.00 |             0.00 |       8000.00 |           0.00 |
| Main Office | 01-992830-4 | Doe, Jane |  5240.44 |            46.00 |       2000.00 |           0.00 |
+-------------+-------------+-----------+----------+------------------+---------------+----------------+
```

I've already tried using `where` and `having` clause but I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: Your expected output does not agree with the description in your question.  Why do you expect these two records to be returned?

Comment: @timbiegeleisen looks ok to me

Comment: I didn’t find a disagreement Tim; he wants something like `select * from table where name not in (select name from table where loan+deposit+time+share =0)` ie because John Doe has one set of empty accounts none of John doe’s details are returned even the full ones (note, i’d probably use left join where x is null rather than not in, but it’s harder to understand as a one liner in a comment and I don’t have time to put an answer right now)

Comment: @Strawberry You're right, didn't see that it is two different people (Jane looks like John at a quick glance).

Answer (score 0):

One option, using summation of the four columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable WHERE t1.Name = t2.Name AND
                  Loans + `Savings Deposits` + `Time Deposits` + `Share Capital` = 0);
```

This answer works by searching, for each record, whether it can find any record with the same name for which the sum of all accounts be zero.  If so, then the name is invalid, and all such name records would not appear in the result set.